# Google Play Console: Blank Screen when clicking Review Terms of Service

Tags: google-play-console

Whenever I open Google Play console a window pop ups asking to review Terms of Service

[image: Terms of Service Pop up]

When I click Review Terms of Service, The below page appears but I cannot see any button to accept terms.
Also clicking on button "Review Terms of Service" fades the screen and display nothing.

Please help me in accepting the new terms before the deadline.

[image: Terms and Services Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working in Google Chrome. If you are facing the same issue, try opening https://play.google.com/console/accept-terms in any other browser.